# Does the function inside the Select clause evaluate the passed in columns before the where clause?

Tags: oracle, functions, cursors

I have a simple select statement that uses a (not so) simple function. I'll try to simplify and demonstrate to the best of my abilities for purposes of this question.

```
            select submission_identifier,
                   submitted_by_person_id,
                   submission_date,
                   form_version_date_time,
                   form_id,
                   func_get_open_days_2(
                     submitted_by_person_id, 
                     submission_date, 
                     form_version_date_time, 
                     form_id)` open_days
            from form_submission
            where submission_identifier = 2070;
```

submission_identifier is the PK for the form_submission table, so naturally, this query returns one result.

As you can see, the function takes 4 parameters. I'm assuming the values in those parameters are the results of the query AFTER the where clause has been evaluated. Here is a snippet of the function.

```
create or replace function        func_get_Open_Days_2
   ( SUBMITTED_BY_PERSON_ID in number,
  SUBMISSION_DATE in date,
  FORM_VERSION_DATE_TIME in timestamp,
  FORM_ID in number
   )
RETURN number

IS
   n1 number:=0;
   n2 number:=0;

   cursor records is
      SELECT 
        SUBMITTED_BY_PERSON_ID,
        SUBMISSION_DATE,
        FORM_ID,
        FORM_VERSION_DATE_TIME,
        AUDIT_DATE_TIME,
        STATUS_DATE,
        SUBMISSION_STATUS_CODE,
        CREATE_USER_ID
      from form_state_audit_trail t
      where
        t.submitted_by_person_id = SUBMITTED_BY_PERSON_ID and
        t.form_id = FORM_ID and
        t.submission_date = SUBMISSION_DATE and
        t.form_version_date_time = FORM_VERSION_DATE_TIME and 
        t.submission_status_code NOT IN (3469, 3462);
        order by t.status_date asc;

   rec records%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

dbms_output.put_line('submitted by person id ='||submitted_by_person_id);
dbms_output.put_line('form id ='||form_id);
dbms_output.put_line('submission date ='||submission_date);
dbms_output.put_line('form_version_date_time ='||form_version_date_time);

  -- go through all the durations in audit_trail table
  FOR rec in records
  LOOP
```

I have tried hard-coding the return values and putting them in this cursor select query. I receive 1 result.

This suggests to me that the "records" array or list should only be 1 result long. **However, I am getting numerous results as it stands now. "records" are being returned which suggest the where clause is not being evaluated using the 4 values/results I'd expect** I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The the "dbms_output.put_line" are the BEGIN but before the LOOP confirm the expected values are reaching the function.

Comment: You've already got an answer, so just to mention another option. Qualifying variables will resolve ambiguity as well (and  [arguably] more readable) . For instance ,  access function argument `FORM_ID` within the body of function as `func_get_Open_Days_2.FORM_ID` , etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The references in the function's `WHERE` clause are comparing with the identically named columns in its `SELECT` clause, rather than the argument list. Try changing it as follows (note the addition of `ARG_` to the argument names and the predicates in the `WHERE` clause):

```
create or replace function        func_get_Open_Days_2
   ( ARG_SUBMITTED_BY_PERSON_ID in number,
  ARG_SUBMISSION_DATE in date,
  ARG_FORM_VERSION_DATE_TIME in timestamp,
  ARG_FORM_ID in number
   )
RETURN number

IS
   n1 number:=0;
   n2 number:=0;

   cursor records is
      SELECT 
        SUBMITTED_BY_PERSON_ID,
        SUBMISSION_DATE,
        FORM_ID,
        FORM_VERSION_DATE_TIME,
        AUDIT_DATE_TIME,
        STATUS_DATE,
        SUBMISSION_STATUS_CODE,
        CREATE_USER_ID
      from form_state_audit_trail t
      where
        t.submitted_by_person_id = ARG_SUBMITTED_BY_PERSON_ID and
        t.form_id = ARG_FORM_ID and
        t.submission_date = ARG_SUBMISSION_DATE and
        t.form_version_date_time = ARG_FORM_VERSION_DATE_TIME and 
        t.submission_status_code NOT IN (3469, 3462);
      order by t.status_date asc;
```